# How can I query a date?

Tags: php, mysql

In update.php file I have

```
$fst_DA = $_GET['1st_DA'];
```

where `'1st_DA'` is from `<input type="date" name="1st_DA">`.

and a query like: 
`mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE familyplanning SET 1st_NS = '" . $fst_NS . "' WHERE FP_ID = 1;");`

I tried the query manually on sqlyog and its working fine, but when I try it on php its not working.
Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries#t=201609131833322763567

Comment: Is your input inside a <form> ?

Comment: Change `WHERE FP_ID = 1;");` to `WHERE FP_ID = 1");`

Comment: if it doesn't work in php, then something failed. Check for errors

Comment: @AlexisCôté fixed it..sorry I'm so sleepy and need to do this in just 5 hours

Comment: @HailHydra *"Change WHERE FP_ID = 1;"); to WHERE FP_ID = 1");"* - The extra semi-colon is valid; it won't break their code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Really? >:) why are you following me, I hate you, I mean thanks I didnt know this

Comment: *"fixed it"* - Enlighten us ;-) "what" exactly fixed it?

Comment: *"Really? >:) why are you following, I hate you"* - I beg your pardon? That's a joke I hope. Edit: ah you edited ;-) you'e welcome.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it is, but seriously I didn't know it

Comment: @AlexisCôté yes it is

Comment: @HailHydra (wink) *cheers*

Comment: How is it valid though @Fred-ii-? I never Knew about that..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mean I edited the content of my question

Comment: @KervonRyan It's (the semi-colon) just an "end of statement" character. It would be a different story if let's say they were in a loop. I.e.: `while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));{...}` would "stop" right there and ignore the rest. It won't throw an error neither, strangely enough.

Comment: Oh ok.. learned something new then.

Comment: You're just ASSUMIng the query succeeds. mysqli will return boolean false on failure: `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($con));` will tell you if/when something barfed.

Comment: ...and error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @kielou There are a few answers below for you. If that doesn't solve the question, then you'll need to post more code, and/or place a comment under the answers.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try convert you date in input in a valid date  (check for your date format)  eg:

```
"UPDATE familyplanning 
 SET 1st_DA = STR_TO_DATE( '" . $fst_DA . "', '%d,%m,%Y') WHERE FP_ID = 1;"
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be some errors:

Did you get fill **$fst_NS** variable before **mysqli_query** ?
Maybe you have to add input form with **name="fst_NS"** instead of **name="1st_DA"** ?

It may depends of form "action" attribute (GET or POST).

If you use:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
```

you could get value by **$_POST**

Else if you use:

```
<form action="update.php" method="get">
```

you could get value by **$_GET**